# I am using GeoServer for fetching vector data in GeoJson format, Can we use variable instead of key name to fetch the data from GeoJson file

Tags: geojson, vector

I want to use variable "value_attribute" instead of static value "Villages"

My Code is below:

```
$(function () {
    $("#attributes" ).change(function () 
    {
        
        var value = document.getElementById("value");
        var value_layer = $('#layer option:selected').text();
        var value_attribute = $('#attributes option:selected').text();
        
       
        value.options[0] = new Option('Select Value1', "");

        $(document).ready(function(){

            var url = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=DSS:XYZ_RP_xyz_pop_dens&propertyName="+value_attribute+"&outputFormat=application/json"
                
            var select = $('#value');
            alert(url)
            $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
                
                let text = value_attribute;
                const uniqueIcons = new Set();
                data.features.forEach((item) => {
                                    
                    uniqueIcons.add(item.properties.Villages);
                  });
                  
                  for(let icon of uniqueIcons) {
                    //console.log(icon);
                    select.append("<option class='ddindent' value='"+ icon +"'>"+icon+"</option>");
                  }
                  

              });
            });
});});
```

Comment: it is not working  undefined message is showing but my concern is  to pass villages value through variable

Comment: what properties are available? what does a describefeaturetype request give?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I am working on the Query box on Vector Data. USer is selected Vector Layer then in next option value it is showing the Layer attribute when user select the attribute in next option box the attribute data will be shown. my GeoJson file dynamically created and each time the Json properties has changed so i want put the properties value in variable and add(item.properties.variablename) function. thanks